# Allow +'s in URL Rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want my url rewrite to allow Plus signs in the string so that i dont have the yucky %20 all over.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z-\s_]+)/([A-Za-z-\s_]+)/([A-Za-z-\s_]+)$ display.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [L]
```

How would i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape it with `\+` in your `regex`

Comment: Actually I'm not sure you can do what you want to, when does the `+` turn into a `%20`, I thought that spaces did that?

Comment: basicly i was saying that i wanted so i could use +'s in my urls instead of %20's in order for php to recognize a space. Thank you this is what i needed!